# hibernate best practice

Tags: hibernate

I was just wondering what is the best way to use hibernate & spring in our Application,
like i have implemented hibernate in my web application.
Every thing is working fine but the thing is i have a list of classes which i have in my applicationcontext.xml class 
Now when i need to use any of those classes I make object of this applicationContext.xml class as below

```
     ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "applicationContext.xml");
    MySQLRdbSpringHelper rdbHelper = (MySQLRdbSpringHelper) ctx.getBean("ManagerJobs");
```

but by this method ,the program invokes all of the classes in application context.xml(below) in the List which uses more memory, isn't there a way to invoke the only class which we need one at a time..?

```
   <bean id="sessionFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
     <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
     <list> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.Employer</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.StatesProvinces</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.EmployerJobs</value> 
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateResumeInfo</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateSkills</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.CandidateInfo</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.SelectedResumes</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.SecretQuestionsBean</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.Categories</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.EducationLevel</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.Salary</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.JobLevel</value>
<value>com.zrsol.joblistings.shared.EmployerCvSearches</value>
     </list> 
     </property> 
     </bean>
      <bean id ="ManagerJobs" class= "jobsite.persistence.MySQLRdbSpringHelper">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application context should be created once, and only once, at the startup of your application. You should never build a new one after. And you should use dependency injection rather than getting your bean from the context. That's the whole point of Spring.

I'm sorry, but you should definitely re-read the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html).